# Correct result for this integral $\int \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{2 \cos \left(5 \sqrt{x}+4\right)+2}+2}+2}}{\sqrt{x}}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

Wolfram|Alpha and its CAS, Wolfram *Mathematica* are, as far as I know, the only website and software that give the correct solution to this [integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20sqrt%282%2Bsqrt%282%2Bsqrt%282%2B2*cos%285*sqrt%28x%29%2B4%29%29%29%29*x%5E%28-1%2F2%29),
$$ f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{2 \cos \left(5 \sqrt{x}+4\right)+2}+2}+2}}{\sqrt{x}} $$
$$ F(x) = \int f(x)\, dx$$
because deriving the function given as result and using the **FullSimplify** function of *Mathematica* we get to the original function that we wanted to integrate.

This is the solution:
$$ F(x) = \frac{1}{5} (-8) \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\cos \left(5 \sqrt{x}+4\right)+1} \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\cos \left(5 \sqrt{x}+4\right)+1}+2} \left(\sqrt{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\cos \left(5 \sqrt{x}+4\right)+1}+2}-2\right) \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\cos \left(5 \sqrt{x}+4\right)+1}+2}+2} \csc \left(5 \sqrt{x}+4\right) + C $$

Fricas finds another expression for the integral that I'm curious about:

$$ F(x) = \frac{1}{5} (-8) \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\sqrt[4]{2} \sqrt{\sqrt{\cos \left(5 \sqrt{x}+4\right)+1}+\sqrt{2}}+2} \left(\sqrt{2} \cos \left(5 \sqrt{x}+4\right)-2 \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\cos \left(5 \sqrt{x}+4\right)+1} \left(\sqrt{\cos \left(5 \sqrt{x}+4\right)+1}+\sqrt{2}\right)+2 \sqrt{\cos \left(5 \sqrt{x}+4\right)+1}+\sqrt{2}}\right) \csc \left(5 \sqrt{x}+4\right) + C$$

However, in [this video,](https://youtu.be/i_TPFIN-NqA?t=621) an incorrect result is given although the integration process seems correct. As above, you know that the result is incorrect since deriving the resulting function doesn't result in the original function we wanted to integrate.

Is the expression given by Fricas equivalent to the one given by Wolfram|Alpha and *Mathematica*?

**Final update**: According to *Mathematica*, the expression given by FriCAS is **not equal** to the correct solution given by *Mathematica* and Wolfram|Alpha. This means it is not the solution to this problem.

Even though I have a Pro Premium subscription, the step-by-step solution is not available for this input. What are the steps taken by *Mathematica*/Wolfram|Alpha to get to the given result?

[image: Wolfram|Alpha results]

Comment: Please, make the question self-contained, reporting the integral using MathJax

Comment: How do you know the answers aren't related by trig identities? They should be, for at least part of the domain

Comment: A person told me "Your function is f = abs(h), where h = 2*cos(5/8*sqrt(x)+1/2)/sqrt(x). Rather that integrating f, it seems to have integrated h."

But that is [wrong](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C2*cos%285%2F8*sqrt%28x%29%2B1%2F2%29%2Fsqrt%28x%29%7C+%3D+sqrt%282%2Bsqrt%282%2Bsqrt%282%2B2*cos%285*sqrt%28x%29%2B4%29%29%29%29*x%5E%28-1%2F2%29)

Comment: That is correct; see my edit for more information.

Comment: If that is correct, why Wolfram|Alpha says that the functions are not equal? Look at [the plots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7C2*cos%285%2F8*sqrt%28x%29%2B1%2F2%29%2Fsqrt%28x%29%7C%2C+sqrt%282%2Bsqrt%282%2Bsqrt%282%2B2*cos%285*sqrt%28x%29%2B4%29%29%29%29*x%5E%28-1%2F2%29), they are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the steps to get to the given result:

$$f(x)=\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}}
=\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\,\dfrac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}}}$$
$$=\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\,\dfrac{\sqrt{2-2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}}$$
$$=\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\,\dfrac{\sqrt{4-4\cos^2(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}$$
$$=\dfrac25\,\dfrac{2\cdot\dfrac5{2\sqrt x}\,|\sin(5\sqrt x+4)|}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}$$
$$=-\dfrac{4}5\,\dfrac{\operatorname{sign}(\sin(5\sqrt x+4))\cdot(2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4))'}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}\;2\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}$$
$$=-\dfrac{8}5\,\dfrac{\operatorname{sign}(\sin(5\sqrt x+4))\cdot\left(2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}\right)'}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}}\;2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}}$$
$$=\dfrac{16}5\,\dfrac{\operatorname{sign}(\sin(5\sqrt x+4))\cdot\left(2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}\right)'}{2\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}}}$$
$$=\dfrac{16}5\,\operatorname{sign}(\sin(5\sqrt x+4))\cdot\left(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}}\right)'.$$

Now we can easily verify that the function
$$F(x)=\dfrac{16}5\,\operatorname{sign}(\sin(5\sqrt x+4))\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}}+C$$
corresponds to the given one in the OP.

Comment: I don't understand this: $$=\dfrac25\,\dfrac{2\cdot\dfrac5{2\sqrt x}\,|\sin(5\sqrt x+4)|}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}\sqrt{2+2\cos(5\sqrt x+4)\large\mathstrut}}$$

How did you put that square root dividing in the numerator?

Comment: @Rodrigo Just algebra.

Comment: @RodrigoSambade He just pulled it from 1/sqrt(x) in the front. Still I must give full expression to my astonishment: this is just amazing (to me at least)!

Answer (score 7):

This is a partial solution, equivalent to the process used in the video, which is only valid if
$$\cos\frac t2$$
[is non-negative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28t%2F2%29%3E%3D0).

Start with this identity:

$$\sqrt{2+2\cos t} = \sqrt{4\cos^2\frac t2} = 2\cos\frac t2$$
For applying this to the integrand, first make the substitution $t = \sqrt x$, then successively apply this property.
$$\begin{gather}
I = \int\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + 2\cos(5t+4)}}}\cdot 2dt\\
= \int\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2+2\cos\left(\frac{5t+4}{2}\right)}} \cdot 2 dt\\
= \int\sqrt{2 + 2\cos\left( \frac{5t+4}{4}\right)} \cdot 2dt \\
= \int 4\cos\left(\frac{5t+4}{8}\right) dt \\
= \frac{32}{5}\sin\left( \frac{5\sqrt x + 4}{8} \right) + C
\end{gather}$$

Comment: This is only true for part of the domain, because you're taking the positive side of absolute value each time. So this answer agrees with the true antiderivative only part of the time. Calling it "the correct answer" is misleading.

Comment: (+1). As @NinadMunshi says, it is interesting that the identity of the first line of your post is valid only if $\cos t/2$ is positive.