# Why does Wolfram|Alpha/Mathematica say that $\sqrt{\cos ^2(t)}=\cos (t)$ in the solution of this integral $\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

In the integral in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1cLdy8MzQU&list=PL256A26E3F9DFEE5D&index=24), Wolfram|Alpha and Wolfram *Mathematica* say that $\sqrt{\cos ^2(t)}=\cos (t)$, when the truth is $\sqrt{\cos ^2(t)}=\left| \cos (t)\right|$.

Why in this case it is using it?

Comment: If $\cos(t)$ is positive over the substitution range that you care about, it is not a mistake.

Comment: You've left off a lot of context, and I am not going to watch a video to see what is missing, but think about where that $\cos(t)$ enters into the problem (hint:  is it coming from an inverse trig function?), and what quadrant that means $t$ could live in.  In the places where $t$ could live, what is the sign of $\cos(t)$?

Comment: [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sqrt%5BCos%5E2%5Bt%5D%5D) has the absolute value. There must have been extra assumptions put in for Wofram to simplify the expression to get rid of the absolue value. This can happen with the Assumptions keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The substitution being made is $t = \arcsin x$ whose range is $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Observe that $\cos t \ge 0$ for all $t$ in the range.

Answer (score 0):

**Straight to the point**

You are correct. Technically $\sqrt{\cos^2  t} = |\cos t|$ instead of just $\cos t$. But for indefinite integrals, we don't really care.

**So does this mean I can always do this?**

When doing indefinite integrals, we tend not to care too much about the domain of $t$ we are working with, and just pick the 'easiest' branch, which in this case is the branch where $|\cos t| = \cos t$ or in other words wherever $\cos t \geq 0$.

**Can you show me an example where it matters?**

Choosing the branch is however needed if the question were a definite integral. For a concrete example, consider $$\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{0}{\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx}$$ For the above, you would need to use a substitution $x=\sin t$ but for a specific domain of $t$ so that the transformation is one-to-one. The most natural domain to use is $t \in \left [ -\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right ]$ in which case $\cos t \geq 0$ so $\sqrt{\cos ^2 t} = \cos t$.

But suppose you decided to use $t \in \left [\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{3\pi}{2} \right ]$. In that domain, $\cos t \leq 0$ and so $\sqrt{\cos^2 t} = - \cos t$

Comment: Then why in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3791843/702373) W|A takes the absolute value?

Comment: No matter how abstract your indefinite integral is, it should remain valid when a legitimate integration interval is applied; as such, we should care that $\sqrt{\cos^2  t} = |\cos t|$ even when performing indefinite integration. @Rodrigo